# How do I ajax using jquery, mongoose, ejs and express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm a noob at backend. I'm developing an ajax comment system for my project. Specifically, I'm looking to add a reply function to a particular comment.

This is what I have in my route:

```
router.post("/posts/:id", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
    if(err){
       console.log(err);
    } else {
      Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            comment.author.id         = req.user.id;
            comment.author.username   = req.user.username;
            comment.author.avatar     = req.user.avatar;
            //Connect new comment to campground
            comment.save();
            post.comments.push(comment)
            post.save()
            //Redirect
            res.redirect('/posts/' + post._id)
        }
      })
    }
 })
```

and for my ajax i have:

```
    $(".commentSubmit").on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    //Find ID of post
    var articleId = $("article").data("id");
    //Find Id of the comment which is being replied to
    var divParent = $(this).closest(".comment-payload");

    $.ajax({
         url: "/posts/" + articleId,
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json"
         }).done(function(result){
            addComment(result);
         })
         .fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
         })


    var addComment = function (comment) {
        var payload = "<div>" + comment + "</div>";
        divParent.append(payload);               
    }

})
```

Where I'm identifying the comment which a user is replying to and adding the reply on the same div.

At the moment two issues(that I know of) arise from this code:

1) When I press submit, the result goes to the div intended but the whole post is added as the reply. I think this comes from my lack of knowledge on how EXPRESS sends back the responses.

2) In my chrome console i get the following: "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." I can't even fathom what this means...

I didn't add my SHOW template nor my schemas to keep this post short but I would be more than happy to edit it if it is necessary.

Any tips for this noob would be appreciated!

Comment: You are not sending any post data to your server from your Ajax call

Comment: Yes, i figured that my route is capturing the data anyways so I didn't feel the need to send the data again...